# Transfer learning with Keras ResNet50 model making python to stop working

Tags: python, keras, theano, resnet

I am using Keras version 2.0.5 with theano as the backend on Python version 3.6.
I am trying to implement a transfer learning by using `ResNet50` model, and have used the code given in the following example: https://keras.io/applications/
Adding the following line to the code is making python to stop working:

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

I have tried changing the model definition as suggested in other links to:

```
model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(3,224,224))
```

but this gives me another error:

> ValueError: The input must have 3 channels; got `input_shape=(3, 224,
>   224)

The code is as follows:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(3,224,224))
```

My theano config file:(theanorc)

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cpu

[nvcc]
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\bin
```

My keras config file:(keras.json):

```
{
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"image_data_format": "channels_first",
"image_dim_ordering": "th",
"backend": "theano",
"floatx": "float32"
}
```

Comment: Do you use `gpu` or `cpu`? Could you show us a full model definition? Could you print out a `model.summary()`?

Comment: I am using cpu. I have changed the image_data_format in keras.json to channels_first. I could not printout model.summary() because my python stops when it encounters the model definition line, i.e. I get a pop-up window stating that "python has stopped executing".

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I guess keras provides the deep learning models in its libraries, check the following link https://keras.io/applications/. I guess this is the resnet50 model code in keras: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet50.py

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that the networks believe you are working with tensorflow data_format. In tensorflow, the channels of the image come last `(im_rows, im_cols, 3)` while with Theano, channels come first `(3, im_rows, im_cols)`.

From the applications documentation (link you gave) :

> All of these architectures (except Xception) are compatible with both TensorFlow and Theano, and upon instantiation the models will be built according to the image data format set in your Keras configuration file at ~/.keras/keras.json. For instance, if you have set image_data_format=channels_last, then any model loaded from this repository will get built according to the TensorFlow data format convention, "Width-Height-Depth".

I will advise you to try this, change the image_data_format to channels_first.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I have changed the keras.json file image_data_format to channel_first. Now, when I execute my code the I get a pop-up window stating "Python has stopped working" and my code doesnt run.

Comment: I don't think this is keras related then. I'm not sure if I can help you further... Sorry

Comment: Yeah @NassimBen is right. It's not Keras related anymore

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the transfer learning by installing anaconda for python 3.5, with keras with the theano backend and it worked. Somehow Python 3.6 installation without anaconda did not work.